# Imcompatible packages when installing Tensorflow using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, dependencies

I try to install Tensorflow using this line in PowerShell (as admin):

```
pip install tensorflow
```

But received this ERROR:

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
> astroid 2.3.2 requires six==1.12, but you have six 1.15.0 which is incompatible.
> astroid 2.3.2 requires wrapt==1.11.*, but you have wrapt 1.12.1 which is incompatible.

Also, I tried to uninstall `six` and `wrapt` using: `pip uninstall six wrapt` and run `pip install tensorflow` again but still got the same error as above.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems like I was opening Anaconda Navigator so it keeps the configuration unchanged. **Solved**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was opening Anaconda Navigator so I closed it and reopened PowerShell again, ran the install command and it went smoothly without further error.